# bizzarre char[] issiu in java. can't copy the values and skip white spaces

Tags: java

B's and G's this is driving me nuts.   I am hoping one of you guru's can save me from stuff my head int he toilet and singing!  I am trying to copy one array fo char's to another without copying the whitespaces.  This is not final code in the sense that it only accounts for ' ' and not the various other forms of whitespace i.e \t.  But that is not the main issue.

```
import java.io;
import java.util.*;

public class tester
{
  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
  {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("intxt.txt"));
    String x = "";
    while(in.hasNext())
    {
      x = in.nextLine();
    }
    System.out.println("This line has  " + x.length() + "characters.");
    char[] charAr = x.toCharArray();
    for(int i = 0; i<charAr.length; i++)
    {
      //prints the int representation of all values
      System.out.print((int)charAr[i] + "  ");
    }
    char[] out = new char[charAr.length];
    for(int i =0; i<out.length; i++)
    {
      char y = ' ';
      if(charAr[i] != y)
      {
        System.out.println("in here " + (int)y);
        out[i] = charAr[i];
      }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i<out.length; i++)
    {
      //should print hellothere
      System.out.print(out[i]+" ");
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Please take the time to reformat this code. Instead of using the ` you can just indent code lines by 4 spaces.

Answer (score 2):

A char array, when constructed, is filled with 0.

Your loop sets the output char array element `i` to the same value as the input char array element `i` if this element is not a whitespace. Otherwise, it leaves the output element as it is (and its value is thus 0).

You need to have seperate indices for your input array and your output array, since you want to skip white spaces. So, assuming the input array has 8 chars and two of them are white spaces, the 6 first elements of your output array should be filled, and the last two ones should be set to whatever you want them to be set.

```
        0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
input:  h e l l o   t h e r e
output: h e l l o t h e r e ?
```

You see in the above example that the indices of the characters don't match.

I assume this is some kind of homework. If it's not, then by all means use a StringBuilder to build your output string.

Comment: thank you!  I am new to being a nerd and I've just finished my first semester senior year.  I held out on using a robust IDE and just used notepad til now.  I was tooling around in eclipse and have been experiencing some weird errors surrounding scanner objects and paths, so I assumed that this was something weird......knucklehead:)  thanks again

Answer (score 0):

```
 while(in.hasNext())
    {
      x = in.nextLine();
    }
```

Shouldn´t be the rest of your code also be within this loop? This loop is pretty meaningless besides picking the last line in "intxt.txt".

Comment: not meaningless homie.  I grab this line and send toCharArray()

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with your code?

I think a good piece of advice would be that if you're not sure about the correctness of the procedure/*algorithm* you're using, adding input-dependent stuff is not clever ...

Hence, I'd initialize `x` with the value you're expected to read from the input file. Is that the string `hello there`, right? So instead of

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("intxt.txt"));
String x = "";
while(in.hasNext())
{
  x = in.nextLine();
}
```

I would simply write

```
String x = "hello there";
```

**NOTE**: I'm assuming it is a typo, but if it's not, first line is wrong. I think you were meant to write

```
import java.io.*;
```

Moreover, write variable identifiers that are more meaningful. `lineRead` is better than `x`, imho.

EDIT: If your expecting to read `hellothere`, with no blanks between characters, you should remove the whitespace appended to every `out[i]`.

```
System.out.println(out[i]);
```

Comment: nope just tooling around with eclipse for the first time doing a real project.  I was trying out an algorithm and thought I came across some anomaly in eclipse.  just got in my own head:)